# Почему на добавленных мною элемента не срабатывает скрипт фокуса?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$('.str_inp input').focus(function () {
    $('.left-side').addClass('foc_blue');
}).blur(function () {
    $('.left-side').removeClass('foc_blue');
});
```

Есть такой код которые добавляет при фокусе на инпут класс другому блоку,но вот при копировании или добавлении элементов с тем же классом и инпутом он не хочет работать.Подскажите в чем может быть причина?
Посмотреть пример данной проблемы можно тут serjo96.github.io/matrix/

Comment: Потому что `$('.str_inp input').focus(` навешивает обработчик только на существующие элементы `$('.str_inp input')`. Используйте `$(document).on("focus", ".str_inp input", function () {...`.

Comment: Лень копаться во всём коде, но уверен - при добавлении нового блока, на него не вешается обработчик. Код выше сработает только один раз и только на тех элементах, которые он найдёт на момент запуска. Используйте делегирование, это более мудрый ход.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

селектор `$('.str_inp input')` возвращает конкретный набор элементов. При вызове `focus(function(){...})` каждому элементу из выбранных добавляется обработчик события `focus`, то же самое относится к `blur`.

Так как добавленных элементов не было в момент добавления обработчика - то у них этого обработчика и нет.

В качестве решения может быть несколько путей:

1. навешивать нужные обработчики *при создании* нового элемента
2. использовать [метод `on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) на контейнере и делегировать обработчики, например, для случая когда инпуты лежат и добавляются в `str_inp`:

   ```
   $('.str_inp').on('focus','input',function(){...});
   ```

При [копировании элементов](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) может быть два случая: без копирования обработчиков и с копированием обработчиков. Все зависит от параметра.